# Error con ItemStateChanged de Combobox

Tags: java, combobox

Tengo dos combobox en un formulario, depende la primer opción del primer combo, debe cargar los resultados referentes a la primer opción, por ejemplo, si elijo la opción de `Sección 1` en mi primer combo, debe cargar todos los empleados referenciados a esa Sección en el segundo combo, hasta cierto punto lo hace, el problema esta en el método del combo de `ItemStateChanged` el cual esta de la sig. manera:

```
    private void cmbo2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
    {                                       
        empList2 = (DplyEmpl)cmbo2.getSelectedItem();
        cmbId2 = empList2.dplyMmbr.toString();
        idCmb2 = Integer.parseInt(empList2.vlMmbr.toString());
    }
```

En este método anterior, lo que hago es que tomo el nombre del empleado y traigo de una lista llamada `DplyEmpl` el valor de su ID para poder realizar mas consultas. Si quito ese código, funciona bien al mostrar las listas, mas no toma ningún valor del combo.

En el combo donde actualizo dependiendo la sección es el siguiente:

```
private void comboSections2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                

        section = comboSections2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(cmbo2 != null)
        {
            cmbo2.removeAllItems();
            cnslt.UpdtCmbEmplysBySctn(cmbo2, section);//Metodo que actualiza el ComboBox
        }
    }
```

El problema comienza en que si dejo el primer código del `cmbo2ItemStateChanged`, no muestra nada y se queda en blanco, si alguien pudiera decirme en donde esta mi error, o alguna manera de hacerlo mas fácil, ya que he buscado maneras distintas pero en muchas vienen a hacer lo mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas obtener el valor del texto del combo únicamente cuando es seleccionado, esto para evitar llamarlo nuevamente, valida únicamente cuando se realiza el evento `SELECTED`:

```
private void cmbo2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {    
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        String textoCombo = cmbo2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
    …
    …
}
```

Comment: El problema no es el obtener el valor, cada que el combo 2 carga los nuevos registros, se vuelve a llamar el ItemStateChange del Combo 2, y es ahi donde tira el error.

Comment: Ok Kevin, revisa mi actualización, realiza tu operación únicamente cuando se realizo la selección del elemento, con eso debes evitar se llame otra vez.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ese era mi error, me has salvado el día.

Comment: Me da mucho gusto, es que en realidad se ejecutan los eventos SELECTED y DESELECTED, por lo tanto tenias que validar únicamente realizara tu operación al "seleccionar" el elemento, saludos!.