# Activar un combobox dependiendo del resultado de otro combobox

Tags: java, sql, combobox

**Quiero cargar en un combobox los valores de éste dependiendo la selección realizada en otro combobox.**

Me explico, tengo una aplicación que permite agregar un coche y quisiera seleccionar los valores mediante consultas dependiendo el valor tomado en un combobox previo. Es decir, realizo una consulta **SQL** para agregar en los items de este **primer cmbobox (marca)**, y automaticamente cargar un **segundo combobox** con los valores del valor del primer combobox**(modelo).**

**CONEXIONES.JAVA**

```
    /**
     * Realizamos una consulta para cargar todas las marcas en el combobox_marcas de Alta_vehiculo.java.
     */
    public static ArrayList cargar_marcas() {
        ArrayList<String> marcas = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todas las marcas.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_marcas = "SELECT descripcion FROM marca;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_marcas);
            System.out.println("CONSULTA TODAS LAS MARCAS: Mostramos todas las marcas de la tabla vehiculos.\n");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String marca = rs.getString("descripcion");
                marcas.add(marca);
                i++;           
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return marcas;
    }



    /**
     * Realizamos una consulta para cargar todos los modelos en el combobox_modelos de Alta_vehiculo.java.
     */
    public static ArrayList cargar_modelos() {
        ArrayList<String> modelos = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los modelos
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_modelos = "SELECT modelo FROM vehiculos;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_modelos);
            System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS MODELOS: Mostramos todoso los modelos de la tabla vehiculos.\n");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String modelo = rs.getString("modelo");
                modelos.add(modelo);
                System.out.println(modelo);
                i++;           
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return modelos;
    }
```

**ALTA_VEHICULO.JAVA**

```
public class Alta_vehiculo extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    public Alta_vehiculo(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Declaramos un arrayList de Strings llamado "marcas".
        ArrayList<String> marcas = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Cargamos los valores de la función "cargar_marcas()" de Conexiones.java en el arrayList "marcas".
        marcas = Conexiones.cargar_marcas();
        //Creamos un iterator para recorrer el ArrayList.
        Iterator<String> i = marcas.iterator();
        //Recorremos el iterator "i".
        while(i.hasNext()){
            //Añadimos a los items cada marca.
            combobox_marca.addItem(i.next());
        }
    }
}
```

**Bien, mi pregunta es: ¿cómo cargo los items de combobox_modelos para que cada modelo vaya con su marca?**

Comment: ¿alguna respuesta?

Comment: Deberías poner el código que has intentado y dónde tienes problemas. Tal cual tienes ahora la pregunta no parece que hayas intentado nada.

Comment: Echa un ojo a este hilo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14525/error-con-itemstatechanged-de-combobox/14535#14535][1], que te puede orientar. De todas formas, deberías explicarte mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, pero ves con cuidado por que se ejecuta al seleccionar y al "deseleccionar"

A través del evento del metodo ItemStateChanged puedes coger el momento de la selección, te pongo un ejemplo simple con dos comboBox de String.

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            

    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
    {
         //Aqui deberias coger el item seleccionado
         String a=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
         //Y aquí a tu función para dar valores al comboBox2 a partir del seleccionado
         if(a.equals("SEAT"))
            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "LEON","IBIZA"}));
          if(a.equals("VW"))  
            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "GOLF","POLO"}));
          if(a.equals("Mercedes"))  
            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Serie 1","Serie 5"}));

    }
}
```

Saludos

EDICIÓN, en la función ItemStateChanged:

```
  if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
    {
         String marcaSeleccionada=(String)combobox_marcas.getSelectedItem();
          //Creamos un Array de String para los modelos
          ArrayList<String> modelos=new ArrayList<String>();
          //la función obtenerModelos nos devuelva una lista de Strings con los modelos de la BBDD dada una marca
          modelos.obtenerModelos(marcaSeleccionada);   

             Iterator<String> i = modelos.iterator();
            //Borramos los datos anteriores del comboBox
            jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                //Añadimos a los items con cada modelo.
                jComboBox2.addItem(i.next());
            }
         }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, te dejo mi código. Mi duda sigue siendo la misma: cargar los items del segundo combobox dependiendo del valor del primer combobox.

Comment: Sabrías hacer una función que que consulte la BBDD según una marca y te devuelva sus modelos? en ese caso en el ItemStateChange:

Comment: Te deje una actualización en mi respuesta, igualmente si en la BBDD tienes ID y DESCRIPCIÓN seria bueno que definieses una clase con ID y descripción y creases los combobox añadiéndole items de esa clase en vez de items del tipo String, pero eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: select modelo from vehiculos as v, marca as m where v.marca = m.id and m.descripcion = "SEAT"; donde SEAT será el valor tomado de la marca en cargar_marcas();

Comment: Pues ahora solo tienes que una función como tu cargar_modelos() pasandole un String con la marca y añadiendole el where a tu consulta.

Iguamente como tienes id y descripción en las tablas, te iría mejor si las listas fueran de un tipo parecido al siguiente:

public class ComboItem {
 
private String text;
private int id;
 
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
 
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
 
public String toString() {
    return text;
}
 
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

Comment: ¿el problema es que no tengo una tabla de modelos... me aconsejais crear la tabla? Tengo los modelos metidos a mano en los insert into de vehiculos, os pongo un ejemplo: 
NSERT INTO VEHICULOS VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", "BLANCO", "2593HBD", 1, "CALIFORNIA", 389, 13.1, "2007/11/03", "Coche CALIFORNIA perfecto para rodar a grandes velocidades."); donde CALIFORNIA es el modelo que va a asociado a la marca 1(FERRARI).

Comment: Te aconsejo crear el comboBox de items de la clase ComboItem que te pase y asi guardas el id como el valor del combobox y la marca/modelo como el texto a mostrar

Comment: igualmente usando la consulta:

String consulta_modelos = "select modelo from vehiculos as v, marca as m where v.marca = m.id and m.descripcion = "+marcaSeleccionada;

También te funcionara siempre que no haya 2 marcas que se llamen igual, aunque siempre es mejor manejarse con IDs.

Comment: me da un error en modelos.cargar_modelos(marcaElegida); el método es: public static ArrayList cargar_modelos(String descripcion) {}

Comment: puedes hacer un preparedStatement o meter "select modelo from vehiculos as v, marca as m where v.marca = m.id and m.descripcion =' "+marcaSeleccionada+"'";, no se que base de datos usas pero al concatenar la marca deberas meterla entre comillas, o meterla como parámetro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona correctamente.